# react-native: project not building after running expo eject

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I recently ejected my Expo project because I needed to install a native module. It built the first time after taking an incredible amount of time, then trying to build again and it keeps saying this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:devMinSdkDevKernelDebugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find host.exp.exponent:expoview:30.0.0.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/home/tushh/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/host/exp/exponent/expoview/30.0.0/expoview-30.0.0.pom
      file:/home/tushh/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/host/exp/exponent/expoview/30.0.0/expoview-30.0.0.aar
      file:/home/tushh/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/host/exp/exponent/expoview/30.0.0/expoview-30.0.0.pom
      file:/home/tushh/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/host/exp/exponent/expoview/30.0.0/expoview-30.0.0.aar
      file:/home/tushh/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/host/exp/exponent/expoview/30.0.0/expoview-30.0.0.pom
      file:/home/tushh/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/host/exp/exponent/expoview/30.0.0/expoview-30.0.0.aar
      file:/home/tushh/Documents/findworka/vapo-and/android/maven/host/exp/exponent/expoview/30.0.0/expoview-30.0.0.pom
      file:/home/tushh/Documents/findworka/vapo-and/android/maven/host/exp/exponent/expoview/30.0.0/expoview-30.0.0.aar
      file:/home/tushh/Documents/findworka/vapo-and/node_modules/expokit/maven/host/exp/exponent/expoview/30.0.0/expoview-30.0.0.pom
      file:/home/tushh/Documents/findworka/vapo-and/node_modules/expokit/maven/host/exp/exponent/expoview/30.0.0/expoview-30.0.0.aar
      file:/home/tushh/Documents/findworka/vapo-and/android/maven-test/host/exp/exponent/expoview/30.0.0/expoview-30.0.0.pom
      file:/home/tushh/Documents/findworka/vapo-and/android/maven-test/host/exp/exponent/expoview/30.0.0/expoview-30.0.0.aar
      https://maven.google.com/host/exp/exponent/expoview/30.0.0/expoview-30.0.0.pom
      https://maven.google.com/host/exp/exponent/expoview/30.0.0/expoview-30.0.0.aar
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/host/exp/exponent/expoview/30.0.0/expoview-30.0.0.pom
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/host/exp/exponent/expoview/30.0.0/expoview-30.0.0.aar
      file:/home/tushh/Documents/findworka/vapo-and/home/node_modules/jsc-android/android/host/exp/exponent/expoview/30.0.0/expoview-30.0.0.pom
      file:/home/tushh/Documents/findworka/vapo-and/home/node_modules/jsc-android/android/host/exp/exponent/expoview/30.0.0/expoview-30.0.0.aar
      file:/home/tushh/Documents/findworka/vapo-and/android/app/libs/expoview-30.0.0.aar
      file:/home/tushh/Documents/findworka/vapo-and/android/app/libs/expoview.aar
      https://jitpack.io/host/exp/exponent/expoview/30.0.0/expoview-30.0.0.pom
      https://jitpack.io/host/exp/exponent/expoview/30.0.0/expoview-30.0.0.aar
      file:/home/tushh/.m2/repository/host/exp/exponent/expoview/30.0.0/expoview-30.0.0.pom
      file:/home/tushh/.m2/repository/host/exp/exponent/expoview/30.0.0/expoview-30.0.0.aar
      https://maven.fabric.io/public/host/exp/exponent/expoview/30.0.0/expoview-30.0.0.pom
      https://maven.fabric.io/public/host/exp/exponent/expoview/30.0.0/expoview-30.0.0.aar
  Required by:
      project :app

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I've tried everything I can, and the issues on GitHub don't provide an explicit way to fix this

Answer (score 0):

try this: `./gradlew devMinSdkDevKernelDebugCompileClasspath --refresh-dependencies`
And if doesnt help. You can try `./gradlew clean` and then go to the AndroidStudion open you project there and `File -> Invalidate Caches / Reset => Invalidate and Reset` and build it again